# Spring getBean for scoped proxy prototype classes

Tags: java, spring

When I try to use applicationContext.getBean() to pass constructor parameters to some prototype class, I am getting below error message, even though I have defined the class as prototype. I am trying to create a new instance of that class every time certain method in a singleton-scoped class is called.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Can
>   only specify arguments for the getBean method when referring to a
>   prototype bean definition

This is the class where I am getting error when trying to call createObject() method.

```
@Component
public class someFactory {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public Foo createObject(String param) {
         return (Foo) appContext.getBean("foo", param);
    }
}
```

This is the sample Foo class:

```
@Component("foo")
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Foo {

     public Foo(String param) {
       //some code
    }
}
```

Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: could it be that getBean requires the class name, and not the @Component name?  What happens when you say getBean("Foo", param) instead of getBean("foo", param)?

Comment: @jrahhali it didnt work, in that case the bean cannot be actually found.

Comment: Which version of Spring are you working with?

Comment: @eyp its Spring 4.0.4